# is empty and cannot be loaded as an image.. Error thrown resolving an image codec

Tags: flutter, dart, caching

In flutter, I used flutter cache manager package to cache images received by calling getImageFile method.

Then I sometimes randomly get this exception. Basically somehow the cached file got deleted.

Is there a fix to this?

Bad state: LocalFile: '/data/user/0/cache/libCachedImageData/485c9400-f425-1d91-abe8-f9c5594e31c6.bin' is empty and cannot be loaded as an image.. Error thrown resolving an image codec.

Should be no exception. If cache not there then download from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this you have cache image or not. Something  like this

```
(cache_image !=null || cache_image.isNotEmpty())? loadCacheImage():Image.network(“https://images.pexels.com/photos/1235542/pexels-photo-1235542.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2”
);
```

I hope you handle your  exception using above code.